# How to install or shift softwares in partition other than root partition

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, unity3d

I have basically 4 partition in my ubuntu machine:

```
eg:
/root
/partition1
/partition2
/partition4
```

I have installed some apps like `vs code` `unity` `inteliJ Idea` and more and my root partition is not at all empty so, I want to actually re-install all of them in other partition `eg: as in partition1`. Then How can I install it? and also ***Unity3D*** ***(with its installed Unity engine 21)*** is such **large** app then how can I **shift** it to other partition and change some settings to make it working? Is shifting app possible?

> I'm running **UBUNTU 20.04 LTS** on my device

So I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Ubuntu is not like Windows. Application software and the OS have many shared libraries. It is not easy to move one or two software to another partition. Best thing to do is to increase the size of the `/` partition.

Comment: But is it possible to install them in other partition

Comment: As specially unity and vs code

Comment: Repartition your system to have a `/` partition sufficiently large for the system. Eventually keep your personal data (/home) on another partition so you do not risk filling the / with user data.